# After forcing www, admin AJAX not working

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx

I recently migrate my server from Apache to Nginx and followed [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento) to write the config file.

I use this piece of code to force www before all urls:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent; ## Forcibly prepend a www
}
```

But now in admin panel, I have this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/710d9916b160c08e3560406812eb3bf3/?SID=kovh5h4r7etpl0v7cn61t6dil3&isAjax=true. The request was redirected to 'http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/710d9916b…r7etpl0v7cn61t6dil3&isAjax=true?SID=kovh5h4r7etpl0v7cn61t6dil3&isAjax=true', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

How could I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: you can fix it by reading your error log message, " which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight"

Answer (score 1):

So you have a static link to http://example.com/

You should probably be fine by modifying base_url or updating your template.